# setNeedsDisplay not calling drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a circular progress indicator.  Unfortunately, the drawRect routine is only called the first and last times from setNeedsDisplay which does not create the gradual fill pattern that I am looking for. I've created a UIView subclass where I populate a background and then update the draw progress as follows:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // draw background
    CGFloat lineWidth = 5.f;
    UIBezierPath *processBackgroundPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    processBackgroundPath.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    processBackgroundPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.width / 2);
    CGFloat radius = (self.bounds.size.width - lineWidth) / 2;
    CGFloat startAngle = (2 * (float)M_PI / 2); // 90 degrees
    CGFloat endAngle = (2 * (float)M_PI) + startAngle;
    [processBackgroundPath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
    [[UIColor grayColor] set];
    [processBackgroundPath stroke];

    // draw progress
    UIBezierPath *processPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    processPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    processPath.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    endAngle = (self.progress * 2 * (float)M_PI) + startAngle;
    [processPath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    [processPath stroke];
}
```

I set the progress variable with the following method:

```
- (void)setProgress:(float)progress {
    _progress = progress;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Then I simply call the attached method in my main viewcontroller after assigning a UIView with the above class to my storyboard:

```
- (void)progressView:(CircularProgress *)activityView loopTime:(CGFloat)duration repeats:(BOOL)repeat {
    float portion = 0.0f;
    while (portion < 1.0f) {
        portion += 1/ (20.0 * duration);
        [activityView setProgress:portion];
        usleep(50000);
    }
}
```

Again, the [self setNeedsDisplay] only calls drawRect the first and last time through.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to `NSTimer`, I can also recommend using [`CADisplayLink`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html):

> A CADisplayLink object is a timer object that allows your application
>   to synchronize its drawing to the refresh rate of the display.
>
> Your application creates a new display link, providing a target object
>   and a selector to be called when the screen is updated. Next, your
>   application adds the display link to a run loop.
>
> Once the display link is associated with a run loop, the selector on
>   the target is called when the screen’s contents need to be updated.

This will ensure that your progress view gets redrawn roughly in sync with the device frame rate.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked.  Thanks so much.  There is a great example at http://zearfoss.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/more-cadisplaylink/.  Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 5):

`usleep(50000)` blocks the thread

Use `NSTimer` instead to updated the progressView.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
duration = 0;
...


- (void)updateProgressView {
    // Update the progress
  }
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I replaced the original method with a timer and method that increments the counter and calls the setProgress method on the custom view.  Unfortunately, I'm still having the same problem.  Open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Both your `drawRect:` and your `progressView:…` methods will be called on the main thread.

`setNeedsDisplay:` doesn't immediately call `drawRect:`; it queues it up to be called the next time your application's main thread passes through its run loop. Use an `NSTimer` or read up on CoreAnimation to see if it provides something more directly applicable: your current solution will eat up a lot of CPU time and will not take advantage of the GPU.